# Why i cannot get the ajax values?

Tags: php, ajax

i try to send some data to my php file from ajax , but i could not  succeed.
This is my ajax file,

```
 var artistIds = new Array();

    $(".p16 input:checked").each(function(){
        artistIds.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });


    $.post('/json/crewonly/deleteDataAjax2',artistIds,function(response){
        if(response == 'ok')
            alert('error');
        else
            alert('nop');
    })
```

and in PHP side i use this code

```
 extract($_POST);

 if(isset($artistIds))
     $this->sendJSONResponse('ok');
 else
     $this->sendJSONResponse('error');
```

$artistIds always come with null
why why why

finally i came to this but also does not work

```
    var artistIds = new Array();

    $(".p16 input:checked").each(function(){
        artistIds.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });


   $.post('/json/crewonly/deleteDataAjax2', { artistIds: artistIds },function(response){
        if(response == 'ok')
            alert('dolu');
        elseif (response == 'error')
            alert('bos');
    });*
```

Comment: sry ... oversaw your extract()

Comment: $artistIds is a array yeah but it is empty

Comment: yeap its empyt in php side, why :S

Comment: i answered, see below :)

Comment: Serialize in jquery and dont use extract in PHP. It is evil.

Comment: +1, just use your $_POST-array or wrap it with a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't post an array without serializing into name-value pairs.

See: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass an object to associate values with names.

```
var data = {
    artistIds: artistIds //Here, the property name is "artistIds", which is going to be the name of your PHP variable. Your JS variable is also called that.
};

$.post('/json/crewonly/deleteDataAjax2',data,function(response){
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Do your $.post like this:

```
$.post('/json/crewonly/deleteDataAjax2', { artistIds: artistIds }, ...);
```

Comment: After looking in the docu, I think you should write it as follows: `$.post('/json/crewonly/deleteDataAjax2', { 'artistIds[]': artistIds }, ....)`. But I am not quite sure